# Redirect stdout and stderr so that it is displayed or stored nowhere

Tags: stdout

I want a process to just NOT print its stdout or stderr output.
 I know that I can do something like
`program >output.txt 2>errors.txt` and then `rm output.txt errors.txt` but its not *elegant*.
I want that they should not at all be stored anywhere in the first place.
Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Just run it as `program >/dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

If you never want it to output stdout or stderr (much like how I have it set up for my Kate text editor) you can add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

`alias kate='kate 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null'`

Just replace `kate` with the needed program, and you should be good to go.