# Running "dpkg -s" or "-l" silent

Tags: scripts, dpkg, output

I am writing a script that checks for a very big list of dependencies. So I wrote a function that gets the package name as input and using `dpkg` checks if it is installed and prints an appropriate output. Here is one version of this function:

```
check_dependency() { 
    dpkg -l $1 > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        # print something saying it is installed
    else
        # print something saying it was not found
    fi
}
```

which works fine when package is installed. But when it is not installed, it somehow doesn't redirect the output to `/dev/null` and prompts:

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching foo-bar
```

In a second attempt, I modifed the body of function to use it with `grep -q`:

```
check_dependency() { 
    dpkg -s $1 | grep -q 'installed'
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        # print something saying it is installed
    else
        # print something saying it was not found
    fi
}
```

When the package is installed, again it seems to work fine, however, when package is not found and unwanted message from `dpkg` appears on terminal:

```
dpkg-query: package 'foo-bar' is not installed and no information is available bla bla...
```

Using directly `dpkg-query` results in similar problem. How to make it silent when it fails to find package?

Comment: Command errors are usually sent to the standard error stream (`stderr`) rather than the standard output stream (`stdout`) - see [Redirect stdout and stderr so that it is displayed or stored nowhere](http://askubuntu.com/questions/298743/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-so-that-it-is-displayed-or-stored-nowhere)

Comment: @steeldriver, It did the job. If you convert you comment to an answer I will accept as *the* answer.

Answer (score 4):

You want to redirect both standard output (stdout) and standard error (stderr) to `/dev/null`.  To do this, replace `>` with `&>`.  This is a shortcut specific to `bash`.  So your code would be:

```
check_dependency() { 
    dpkg -l $1 &> /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        # print something saying it is installed
    else
        # print something saying it was not found
    fi
}
```

However, this would still count a package as being installed if it had been removed but config files remained (as pointed out by @A.B.).  Instead, you could try

```
check_dependency() { 
    # Get the number of packages installed that match $1
    num=$(dpkg -l "$1" 2>/dev/null | egrep '^ii' | wc -l)

    if [ $num -eq 1 ]; then
        # print something saying it is installed
    elif [ $num -gt 1]; then
        # print something saying there is more than one package matching $1
    else
        # print something saying it was not found
    fi
}
```

Comment: Using `dpkg -l $1` and checking the return code says nothing about the installation status of a package.

Comment: I used the `check_dependency` but I had to add extra `[]` in the conditonals to avoid issues

Answer (score 2):

Using `dpkg -l $1` and checking the return code says **nothing** about the installation status of a package.

Use `awk` and `dpkg -l` and check the status `ii`

```
dpkg -l | awk '/^ii +'"$1"' +/'
```

---

*Example*

```
$ package="mc"
$ dpkg -l | awk '/^ii +'"$package" +' /'
ii  mc      3:4.8.13-3      i386       Midnight Commander - a powerful file manager

$ package="foobar"
$dpkg -l | awk '/^ii +'"$package" +' /'
<returns nothing>
```

or

```
$ package="mc"
$ dpkg -l | awk '/^ii +'"$package"' +/ {print $2}'
mc
```